# Let $f\in G$. Show that for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $f(n)=nf(1)$.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

- Let $G=\{f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\,:\, \text{for all }x,y\in \mathbb{Z},\ f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)\}$.
- For $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ define the function $f_a:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ by the formula  $f_a(x)=ax$, $f_a(x)\in G$.

Let $f\in G$. Show that for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $f(n)=nf(1)$. Can you give a hint?

Comment: $f(2)=f(1+1)=f(1)+f(1)=2f(1)$

Comment: see that $n= 1+1\cdots+1+1$

Comment: @GuyFsone Then, should I use induction for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @Kahler yes$ $$ $

Comment: Thanks for comments.

Answer (score 0):

The function $f$ satisfies $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$, for all $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$. In particular
$$
f(0)=f(0+0)=f(0)+f(0)
$$
and therefore $f(0)=0$. This is the base step of the induction.

Suppose the statement holds for $n$. Then, by assumption, $f(n)=nf(1)$ and so
$$
f(n+1)=f(n)+f(1)=\cdots
$$